# Apache HTTPD basic auth creates multiple login dialogs

Tags: httpd, http-basic-authentication

So i have an Apache HTTPD server (v2.4.6) with mod_ssl. I setup basic auth in **/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf** with the code at the end:

```
<LocationMatch "xxxx">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/password
Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

But when I browse to my site in Chrome/Firefox/IE I get the login dialog multiple times (like 3-5).

My webpage itself uses spring security. So it could be the cookies are conflicting with each other?

From an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041002/conflict-between-spring-security-and-basic-authorization-of-tomcat) I have tried option 1 but to no avail.